# Active on next div and on another remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this solution for simple slider, but I need to preserve class .active like as the first class .row

And the buttons will switch .active class like as the first class .row

Currently, it only switches to the .row class but I need to switch to the .first and .second class.

Here is my actual solution:

```js
$(function(){
$("#next").click(function(e) {
  var activeelement = $('.active');
  if(activeelement.next().length)
    activeelement.removeClass('active').next(".row").addClass('active');
  else
    activeelement.removeClass('active').closest('.main').find('> .row:first').addClass('active');
 });

$("#back").click(function(e) {
  var activeelement = $('.active');
  if(activeelement.prev().length)
activeelement.removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
  else
activeelement.removeClass('active').closest('.main').find('> .row:last').addClass('active');
 });
});
```

```css
.main .row {
  display: none;
}
.main .row .active {
  color: blue;
}
.main .active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="row active">
      <div class="first active">sss</div>
      <div class="second active">ss</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="first">sss2</div>
      <div class="second">ss</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="first">sss3</div>
      <div class="second">ss</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="first">sss4</div>
      <div class="second">ss</div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="back">Back</a>
<a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please try to explain problem and/or expected behavior with more detail. Currently it is too vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `children()`

```js
$(function(){
$("#next").click(function(e) {
  var activeelement = $('.active');
  if(activeelement.next().length-1){
    activeelement.removeClass('active').next(".row").addClass('active').children().addClass('active').parent().prev(".row");
    activeelement.children().removeClass('active');
    }
  else{
    activeelement.removeClass('active').closest('.main').find('> .row:first').addClass('active').children().addClass('active');
    activeelement.children().removeClass('active');
    }
 });

$("#back").click(function(e) {
  var activeelement = $('.active');
  if(activeelement.prev().length-1){
  activeelement.removeClass('active').prev(".row").addClass('active').children().addClass('active');
    activeelement.children().removeClass('active');
    }
  else{
    activeelement.removeClass('active').closest('.main').find('> .row:last').addClass('active').children().addClass('active');
    activeelement.children().removeClass('active');
    }
 });
});
```

```css
.main .row {
  display: none;
}
.main .row .active {
  color: blue;
}
.main .active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="row active">
      <div class="first active">sss</div>
      <div class="second active">ss</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="first">sss2</div>
      <div class="second">ss</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="first">sss3</div>
      <div class="second">ss</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="first">sss4</div>
      <div class="second">ss</div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="back">Back</a>
<a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
```